# Swift: Popup with Active tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, popup

What I would like to do is to show a popup and still be able to interact with the `tableview` and popup at the same time.

Interaction: Being able to scroll the `tableview` and select cells while the popup is shown.

I have attached a link to a video that does exactly what I am trying to achieve: [Video](https://streamable.com/mzizn)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please show the code you have tried to use. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask   https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Create a custom view that mimics as a popup with animations.

Answer (score 0):

Add alertview/popup as subview in your viewcontroller. By doing this popup will by controlled by your viewcontroller.